# The R letter in the LR parsing system

Tags: parsing

I try to understand how  the LR parsing work.  The L means that the parser reads input text in one direction without backing up; that direction is typically Left to right within each line, and top to bottom across the lines of the full input file.

The R means that the parser produces a Rightmost derivation in reverse. my problem is with R i cant understand what it mean.

just i know  right-most derivation for this grammer:
E → E + E | E * E | (E) | id

is as follows:

E → E + E → E+ E * E → E + E * id3 → E + id2 * id3 → id1 + id2 * id3

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An LR parser discovers the rightmost derivation *backwards*. So in your example, the derivations it would discover would be, in order:

```
stack • input          derivation
-----------------      ----------
• id1 + id2 * id3      E → id1
E + • id2 * id3        E → id2
E + E * • id3          E → id3
E + E * E •            E → E * E
E + E •                E → E + E 
E •
```

Comment: • id1 + id2 * id3      E → id
E + • id2 * id3        E → id